# Max value of sum of squares

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Question is

Sum of two numbers x and y is 10.
What is the maximum and minimum value of its sum of squares.

How can I find the maximum?

The minimum turns out to be 50 using AM GM

Please do try to solve this using AM GM

Please help me out..

Yeah I found its min value and then I went on a long way for it's max value but failed

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yeah I found its min value and then I went on a long way for it's max value but failed

Comment: @ParclyTaxel   I tried using quadratic means and harmonic means. Can you please help me out. I am not able to go on any further.

Comment: I need restrictions on $x,y$. Are they positive? Nonnegative?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Oops I am sorry I forgot to mention it. They are non negative

Comment: You are looking for the maximal value of $x^2 + (10-x)^2$ on the interval $[0, 10]$. That is a *parabola.* Try to sketch it.

Comment: Try $x=10,y=0$.

Comment: Better please if you can do it using AM GM inequality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we take AM $\ge$ GM for $x^2$ and $y^2$, we get

$\frac {x^2+y^2} 2 \ge \sqrt{x^2y^2}$

$x^2+y^2 \ge 2xy$

$\implies$ $(x+y)^2 - 2xy \ge 2xy$

$\implies$ $100 \ge 4xy$

$\implies$ $xy \le 25$

Here you can find max value of $xy$, you already have found min value of $x^2+y^2$.

> Max value of $x^2+y^2$ does NOT exist.

You may understand this as, the graph being parabolic so no global extrema.

Comment: Good solution but the book is asking for the max value using AM GM inequality. I don't know Co ordinate.

Comment: If you can look into it and if it does not exist then give me a proof other than parabola as I don't know what it is.

Comment: @user606630, parabola is the graph that is formed for any quadratic equation. Quadratic equation is of form $ax^2 + bx + c$ where $a$ is non zero. Read more about Parabola here, https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjyo5ne8JfeAhVKzRoKHRPqCQQQFjAAegQIBxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FQuadratic_equation&usg=AOvVaw01QVMhWajPlbXa2jfWsave

Comment: @user606630 check the question once more, if you find that you are really asked the maximum value of $x^2+y^2$, say infinity or does not exist. You may try the maximising and minimising the function Jose gave in his answer, you will get the same answer.

Comment: @user606630 did this help you?

Comment: @PradyumanDixit, surely as $0 \leq x \leq 10$ and $0 \leq y \leq 10$, then $x^2 + y^2$ has a maximum subject to the constraint $x + y = 10$?

Comment: @PradyumanDixit, indeed if I am not mistaken I think we have $x^2 + y^2 \leq 100$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  $x+y=10$, hence you ought to minimize and maximize the function 
$$f(x) = x^2 + (10 - x)^2 = 2x^2 - 20x + 100 = 2(x^2 - 10x + 50).$$

Can you take it from here?

**Added December 23 2018**

A plot of the graph of $f(x) = 2(x^2 - 10x + 50)$ taken from WolframAlpha is as follows:
[image]

Clearly, the maximum value ($100$) of $f$ occurs at the endpoints $x = 0$ and $x = 10$, while the minimum may be computed via the critical number $c$ as follows:
$$f'(x) = 2(2x - 10)$$
$$f'(c) = 0 = 2(2c - 10)$$
$$c = 5$$
$$f''(x) = 4 > 0$$

Therefore, the minimum value ($50$) of $f$ occurs at $x = 5$.

Comment: No no we only can use AM GM inequality